# Replace Grails plugin listener

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I need to extend the listener class of [audit-logging plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging), in order to provide different functionality on some scenarios.

For that purpose I have created this class:

```
class CustomAuditLogListener extends AuditLogListener{

  public CustomAuditLogListener(Datastore datastore) {
    super(datastore)
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreUpdate(event) {
     . .  .
}
}
```

Now, in order for the plugin to use this class instead of the default 
AuditLogListener, within Bootstrap.groovy I try to remove AuditLogListener from the application listeners, and add the custom listener:

```
 def applicationContext = servletContext.getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
    log.debug("Application listeners - PRE")
    log.debug(applicationContext.getApplicationListeners())
    // Remove all the listeners registered by the audit plugin.
    applicationContext.getApplicationListeners.each { listener ->
      if (listener.class == AuditLogListener.class) {
        servletContext.getApplicationListeners.remove(listener)
        log.debug("AuditLogListener removed ")
      }
    }

    grailsApplication.mainContext.eventTriggeringInterceptor.datastores.each { key, datastore ->
      // Don't register the listener if we are disabled
      if (!grailsApplication.config.auditLog.disabled && !datastore.config.auditLog.disabled) {
          def listener = new CustomAuditLogListener(datastore)
          listener.with {
             // some options
          }
          applicationContext.addApplicationListener(listener)
          log.debug("Add new listener CustomAuditLogListener")
      }
    }
    log.debug("Application listeners -POST")
    log.debug(applicationContext.getApplicationListeners())
```

> Application listeners - PRE returns empty list
>
> Add new Listener CustomAudtilogListener is logged
>
> Application Listeners - POST returns empty list

The way I register my listener is copied from the way the plugin registers the listener, seen in this [class](https://github.com/robertoschwald/grails-audit-logging-plugin/blob/master/grails-audit-logging-plugin/AuditLoggingGrailsPlugin.groovy)

To sum, what I need is replacing AuditLogListener, with my own CustomAuditLogListener. Currently the above process is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey sorry but the post does seem a little confusing, although I think I understand

> I need to extend the listener class of audit-logging plugin.
>
> Now, in order for the plugin to use this class instead of the default
>   AuditLogListener,

so you are trying to override the auditLogListener.

Your problem maybe that you are not declaring it as an override in your conf/spring/resources.groovy.

I have done a similar thing for a class rather than listener here:

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testwschat/blob/master/test/unit/anythingbut/grails/plugin/wschat/MyOverrideServiceSpec.groovy

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testwschat/blob/master/grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy

and something similar here:

[grails kickstart plugin KickstartFilters how to prevent password information on logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293945/grails-kickstart-plugin-kickstartfilters-how-to-prevent-password-information-on)

basically once you declare your bean

`yourAppFilters(KickstartFilters)`

This then tricks your grails-app and any plugins that maybe referring to KickstartFilters to now refer to yourAppFilters as the replacement

Try a bean like this: (ctrl shift o) to pull in CustomAuditLogListener

```
AuditLogListener(CustomAuditLogListener){
 grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
}
```

Comment: I have followed the steps on this blog (http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/extending-audit-logging-plugin-to-track-changes-to-persistent-collections)  where comments suggest it worked, although it didnt for me, and it kind of makes sense as simply declaring a bean shouldnt affect listeners..

Comment: but right at the bottom it has the bean declaration did you also put that all in too ? auditLogListener(CustomAuditLogListener) {
       sessionFactory   = ref('sessionFactory')
       verbose          = application.config?.auditLog?.verbose?:false
       transactional    = application.config?.auditLog?.transactional?:false
       sessionAttribute = application.config?.auditLog?.sessionAttribute?:""
       actorKey         = application.config?.auditLog?.actorKey?:""
   }

Comment: that documentation is going back a few years ago, if you look at the code it was last updated in Nov 2014. How about trying a bean like above - just updated my anwer with a new bean, I could not see sessionFactory in the code like it was defined in the bean from within the docs in the link above.

Comment: Ensure your override call matches actual plug in version of code. Also unsure but maybe you need to activate your listener. Take a look at grails-websocket-example on my github that initialises websocket listener through scripts/events.groovy for a grails-app

Comment: I ended up following a different approach that didnt need to change listener, just remembered to close this question. Thanks for your help